# Update SQL Server database dynamically in VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to generate a query dynamically using textbox values from my Bookings form to update only those values that were entered by the user.

I am using the following code:

```
Dim str As String

str = "UPDATE Bookings SET "
Dim first As Integer = 1
For Each x As Control In Me.Controls
    If x.GetType Is GetType(TextBox) Then
        If first = 1 Then
            first = 2
        Else
            str &= ","
        End If
        If x.Tag = 1 Then
            str = str & x.Name & " = @" & x.Name
        End If
    End If
Next
```

But it is generating the query like this:

```
Update Bookings SET ,,booking_date = @booking_date,,,,,cust_name = @cust_name where bookingID = @bookingID
```

Or if I want to update just 1 field it generates this:

```
Update Bookings SET ,,,,,,,cust_name = @cust_name where bookingID = @bookingID
```

Comment: I know this does not answer your question at all, but please consider using SQLCommand and SQLParameters if this code is meant for production use. Generating SQL like that is a massive security flaw :)

Comment: I've used sqlcommand and sql parameters and this code is just to generate a query at run time for textboxes having a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim str As String  
str = "UPDATE Bookings SET "
Dim comma As string = ""
For Each x As Control In Me.Controls
  If x.GetType Is GetType(TextBox) Then
    If x.Tag = 1 Then
      str &= comma & x.Name & " = @" & x.Name
      comma = ","
    End If
  End If
Next
```

And here is the One line answer.

```
Dim str = "UPDATE Bookings SET " & String.Join(",", (From _E In Controls.OfType(Of Control)() Where _E.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox) AndAlso _E.Tag = "1" Select _E.Name).ToList())
```

Comment: I have 2 masked text boxes 1 is cust_id and its mask is "csc-   " i.e. four integer values are required after csc- and the other one is contact whose mask is "   -      " i.e. four integer values are required before '-' and 7 integer values are required after '-'......But both these textboxes are not getting validated and i have put .tag = 1 at validated event and i have also tried it at textchanged event but useless and the query is not changed for these if some value is entered in these 2 textboxes...Please suggest a remedy for this